# Consume Webservice using typescript

Tags: web-services, api, rest, typescript, reddit

I am attempting to use typescript to consume a RESTful webservice, and am having a few issues understanding how to write the call.

I want to consume this call for the Reddit API:

POST /api/register

http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

How can I write that post method using Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at amplify.js (http://amplifyjs.com/). This library provides a convenient wrapper around the invocation of REST services and has TypeScript definition filed to facilitate easy consumption from TypeScript.

Comment: Is there any new library that does this work? Amplify.js is not working since 3 years ago.